# AngularJS ng-view not showing up using $routeProvider templates

Tags: javascript, python, html, angularjs, controller

Directory Structure:

```
public
  film
    - film.html
    - film-controller.js
  main
    - main.html
    - film-controller.js
  - app.js
  - index.html
```

In my index.html file I have:

```
<div ng-view> </div>
```

in the body and ng-app="myApp" in the starting html tag

app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).config(config);

function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'main/main.html',
        controller: 'MainController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    }).when('/film/:id', {
        templateUrl : 'film/film.html',
        controller: 'FilmController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/'
    });
}
```

In main.html I have a `<h1>Hello {{vm.name}}</h1>` line of code

In main-controller.js:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController($http) {
    var vm = this;
    $http.get('http://swapi-tpiros.rhcloud.com/films').then(function(response) {
        vm.films = response.data;
    });

    vm.name = 'Joseph';
}
```

So when the page loads I expect to see "Hello Joseph", but instead I get nothing and if I check the console I get no errors. Upon inspecting element, it shows me `<!-- ngView: -->` inside the body tags.
I tested my routing and it should navigate to the right address, but why isn't my template showing up and why is my *ng-view* commented out?

I am running this app using Python's SimpleHTTPServer module, FYI.

Comment: can you try adding slash before main like: 
templateUrl: '/main/main.html' ?

Comment: Thanks, that was a quick and simple fix.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.